# r groupby and filter min and max based on multiple condition

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, group-by, duplicates

I have a dataset like this and I am trying to get rid of duplicates based come conditions

```
  ID   Date        Participant    Source  Col1   Col2   Col3
   1    04/16/2010  3              2      1      0      1
   1    04/16/2010  2              2      1      1      1
   1    04/16/2010  2              1      0      0      1

   2    10/16/2011  2              2      1      1      0
   2    11/06/2008  2              1      2      2      1
   2    11/06/2008  3              1      2      2      1

   3    15/06/2005  3              2      0      1      1
   3    15/06/2005  2              2      0      1      1
```

Here are the conditions.

1. If Source is not 2 then

   ```
      retain the row with minimum of Participant if the columns Source + ID + Dates are same 

      ID   Date        Participant    Source  Col1   Col2   Col3      
      2    10/16/2011  2              2      1      1      0

      2    11/06/2008  2              1      2      2      1

      Because ID 2 has same Date(11/06/2008) and same source(1) get rid of the row with 
     Participant  = 3 and retain rows with Participant  = 2 and source =1 like above.
   ```
2. If the source is 2 then

   ```
     a) retain the minimum of Participant if the columns Source + ID + Dates are same and 
        ID does not have another source other than 2

       ID   Date        Participant    Source  Col1   Col2   Col3 
       3    15/06/2005  2              2      0      1      1      

     b)  retain the maximum of Participant if the columns Source + ID + Dates are same and 
         ID has another source other than 2

       ID   Date        Participant    Source  Col1   Col2   Col3
       1    04/16/2010  3              2      1      0      1

       1    04/16/2010  2              1      0      0      1

       This is bit complicated. Because ID 1 has two sources 1 and 2. Rows are duplicated in 
       Source=2, so retain the row with Maximum of Participant (Participant = 3) for this ID 
       as shown above.
   ```

When I put this all together, the final expected dataset should be like this.

```
       ID   Date        Participant    Source  Col1   Col2   Col3
       1    04/16/2010  3              2      1      0      1
    
       1    04/16/2010  2              1      0      0      1
       2    10/16/2011  2              2      1      1      0
      
       2    11/06/2008  2              1      2      2      1
       3    15/06/2005  2              2      0      1      1
```

I can do a simple group_by and filter based on min or max but not sure how to filter based on multiple conditions like this. Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I believe this solves your problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = " ID   Date        Participant    Source  Col1   Col2   Col3
   1    04/16/2010  3              2      1      0      1
   1    04/16/2010  2              2      1      1      1
   1    04/16/2010  2              1      0      0      1

   2    10/16/2011  2              2      1      1      0
   2    11/06/2008  2              1      2      2      1
   2    11/06/2008  3              1      2      2      1

   3    15/06/2005  3              2      0      1      1
   3    15/06/2005  2              2      0      1      1 ",
   header = TRUE)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Date) %>%
  filter((Source != 2 &
            Participant == min(Participant)) |
           (Participant == min(Participant) &
              all(Source == 2)) |
           (Source == 2 &
              Participant == max(Participant) &
              any(Source != 2)))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 7
#> # Groups:   ID, Date [4]
#>      ID Date       Participant Source  Col1  Col2  Col3
#>   <int> <chr>            <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1 04/16/2010           3      2     1     0     1
#> 2     1 04/16/2010           2      1     0     0     1
#> 3     2 10/16/2011           2      2     1     1     0
#> 4     2 11/06/2008           2      1     2     2     1
#> 5     3 15/06/2005           2      2     0     1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the solution, you hardcoded ID=2 , I like to apply this to a dataset that have many IDs , is there any way to changed that ?

Comment: Oh! Sorry - I misunderstood - I've edited my answer and it now produces the exact 'expected output'